# How to count the amount of 1s in one of the rows in a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I am currently trying to input a matrix and have the python code be able to go row by row to count how many 1s there are in that row. Then I would have all the data be outputted in a row. But right now, I am kind of stumped on how to collect the data and output it in a row.

Note, this is my input method example:

```
2 3
1 1 3
1 2 0
1 2 3
```

output I get:

```
1
1
1
```

output I tried to get:

```
2
1
1
```

Here is the code that I need help fixing:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
#input
for i in range(n):
  l = list(int(m) for m in input().split())
#repeating rows of list inputs for matrix
  
if len(l) < m or len(l) > m:

  
    print("no")
    #if statement for checking length of lists
else:
    for b in range(n):
    #the count function, and unfortunately the part that is wrong                 
        v = l.count(1)
        print(v)
```

I pretty much want to know how to output all the data in a row.

Comment: also, please state any improvements for this question.

Comment: For the purposes of the question, the manual `input()` doesn't really matter. It would be easier to read and answer, if you provided a few statements that just create `l` outright, instead of requiring a user to manually enter it. (also, the input doesn't seem to match the code, it doesn't work as stated) It would also help if you share what the output you get *is* and what you'd expect it to be instead.

Comment: right, thanks one sec, imma' edit it.

Comment: ok I will think if I want to keep the input in the question.

Comment: Off-topic: Suggest you avoid naming a variable `l` because it looks almost the same as `1` in many computer fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues. For one, it would be good to tell a (human) user what they need to enter - an automated user won't care about it either way:

```
print('Enter the number of rows and the length of each row, separated by a space:')
n, m = map(int, input().split())
```

(or you can do that in the `input()` call)

Although your question is really about the final bit of the code, your input code also has an error: you replace the entire list with the input for every iteration, so you only end up with the final row in `l`.

A better way to write the whole input bit:

```
n, m = map(int, input('Number of rows and length of each row, separated by spaces: ').split())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    row = list(map(int, input(f'{m} values, for row {i}, separated by spaces: ').split()))
    if len(row) != m:
        print('Each row must have {m} values!')
        exit()
    l.append(row)
```

But for purposes of your question, you could just write something like:

```
# 2 rows of 3 values
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]]
```

(it makes sense to have some different numbers of 1's on each line?)

Now that the values are actually lists in a list, you can just loop over the lists and do what you were doing:

```
for xs in l:
    v = xs.count(1)
    print(v)
```

The key thing was first *appending* each row the list of lists you were constructing (after all, you're after 2d matrix) and then to loop over each row, and count the elements of each row separately. You can just use `for` as shown to loop over each element of an iterable, like a list.

The result:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
for xs in l:
    v = xs.count(1)
    print(v)
```

The output:

```
1
1
```

Comment: That is a lot of good info.

Comment: You're welcome - if you think this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer, so that your question no longer appears as 'unanswered'. If you feel it doesn't quite answer it, please comment on what is missing.